# How to make a loop or "sum" formula in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: arrays, excel, loops, excel-formula, accumulate

Say that I gain +5 coins from every room I complete. What I'm trying to do is to make a formula in Excel that gets the total coins I've gotten from the first room to the 100th room.

With C++, I guess it would be something like:

```
while (lastRoom > 0)
{
totalCoins = lastRoom*5;
lastRoom--;
}
```

totalCoins, being an array so that you can just output the sum of the array.

So if ever, how do you put this code in excel and get it to work? Or is there any other way to get the total coins?

Comment: Can you give an example of the data you are working with?

Comment: I only have:

Previous room: 1,      
Nth(Current) Room: 100, 
Coin reward for previous room: 5, 
Coin reward for Nth room: 500. 

(The previous and nth rooms may be changed and the coin rewards adjust to the change).

I just need to get the accumulated coins from the previous room all the way to the nth room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are infinite solutions.
One is to build a table like this:

```
+---+----------+---------------+
|   |    A     |       B       |
+---+----------+---------------+
| 1 | UserID   | RoomCompleted |
| 2 | User 001 | Room 1        |
| 3 | User 002 | Room 1        |
| 4 | User 002 | Room 2        |
| 5 | User 002 | Room 3        |
+---+----------+---------------+
```

them pivot the spreadsheet to get the following:

```
+---+----------+-----------------------+
|   |    A     |           B           |
+---+----------+-----------------------+
| 1 | User     | Total Rooms completed |
| 2 | User 001 | 1                     |
| 3 | User 002 | 3                     |
+---+----------+-----------------------+
```

where you have the number of completed rooms for each users. You can now multiplicate the number per 5 as a simple formula or (better) as a calculated filed of the pivot.

Comment: Is there anyway to get the total coins without having to list down all the rooms?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you shouldn't need any special code, just a formula:

```
=(C2-A2+1)*B2
```

Where C2 = Nth room, A2 = Previous Room, and B2 = coin reward. You can change A2, B2, or C2 and the formula in D2 will output the result.

[image]

Comment: Oh, I see..but how can I get the total coins collected? This is what I have right now: 
[link](http://s1264.photobucket.com/user/mkeiz0/media/adsasdasdsad.jpg.html?t=1490699194)

Comment: I'm not sure what the total coins collected means. This gives you a total of coins for the rooms completed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formula for sum of integers less than n: `(n - 1)*(n / 2)`, then multiply it by coin count so you will get something like: `5 * (n - 1)*(n / 2)`. Then you just hook it up to your table.
Hope it helps

Comment: posting this for anyone who lands on this thread like i did, although it is old question